# storing python function in distributed computer

Tags: python, tornado

finally I a little understand about tornadoweb asynchronous

the key of asynchronous response is

> ```
> def new_messages(self, messages):
>     cls = MessageMixin
>     logging.info("Sending new message to %r listeners", len(cls.waiters))
>     for callback in cls.waiters:
>         try:
>             callback(messages)
>         except:
>             logging.error("Error in waiter callback", exc_info=True)
>     cls.waiters = []
> ```

so Is there any solution to store the callback function in datastore
or solution if using several computer or process??

e.g : 
A request updates to node1
B post data for A that handled by node2

how to node2 call node1 callback??

Answer (score 0):

What?! You can only do callbacks with a message queue that has a data store. Look into something pika or Carrot. There's no way to "store" the callback but you can define a way to make other computers execute functions for you and have the results fed back to the original computer.